# Android: AlertDialog inside another AlertDialog Action

Tags: android

1. When I click on confirmDialogAlert "Cancel" the secondDialogAlert is opening

   ```
        AlertDialog.Builder secondDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this);
        secondDialogAlert
                .setTitle("!Alert Second Dialog")
                .setMessage("Successfully opened")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Dialog Opened Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).show();

        AlertDialog confirmDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this)
                .setTitle("!Alert First Dialog")
                .setMessage("Are you sure want to continue?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                    secondDialogAlert.show();
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).show();
        confirmDialogAlert.show();
   ```

Comment: please explain what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: What doesn't work with this code?

Comment: I'm trying to call the first Dialog Box, If I try on cancel in first Dialog Box it should not open the second dialog box but it is opening.

Comment: Just remove the `.show()` from `secondDialogAlert` in first block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dialog opens because you are invoking .show() on both dialogs. To solve this you need to change it like this.

In your original code you invoked `.show()` which will display the dialog. What you must do is invoke `.create()`. Then when you want to display the dialog invoke `.show()`;

```
 AlertDialog.Builder secondDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this);
 secondDialogAlert
         .setTitle("!Alert Second Dialog")
         .setMessage("Successfully opened")
         .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Dialog Opened Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create(); // .show() changed to .create()

 AlertDialog confirmDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this)
         .setTitle("!Alert First Dialog")
         .setMessage("Are you sure want to continue?")
         .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
             secondDialogAlert.show();
         }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create(); // invoke create() instead of show because you have invoked it below
 confirmDialogAlert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setNegativeButton handler, instead of using null, call the cancel function of the AlertDialog.

Also, make sure you call `.create()` on your `AlertDialog.Builder` after you finish configuring it but before you call `.show()`.

So you should end up with something like this:

```
AlertDialog secondDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this);
     secondDialogAlert
             .setTitle("!Alert Second Dialog")
             .setMessage("Successfully opened")
             .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Dialog Opened Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    secondDialogAlert.cancel()
                }).create();

     AlertDialog confirmDialogAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(class.this)
             .setTitle("!Alert First Dialog")
             .setMessage("Are you sure want to continue?")
             .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                 secondDialogAlert.show();
             }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    confirmDialogAlert.cancel()
                }).create();
     confirmDialogAlert.show();
```

Comment: No problem, it's nice to help fellow developers